# Get child class name inside super class in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I have a super class named as `Person` and I extend this class as `Employee`. I want to print the name of this extended (child) class inside the super (parent) class.

Is this possible? If so, how can I print the child class name?

Comment: on extension phase - yes (subclass hook)

Comment: All of a class's base classes are available via the class's `__bases__` attribute; that is, `Person` will appear in the tuple `Employee.__bases__`.

Comment: @chepner I believe that the inverse is desired here. `class Employee(Person)`, and get the name of `Employee` from `Person`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, I want to get the name `Employee` from `Person` super class

Comment: Oops. Then you can check the return value of `Person.__subclasses()__` (which is a list of *all* subclasses; it's up to you to identify which subclass you are actually interested in. As an example, try `object.__subclasses__()` sometime.).

Comment: haha nice! warning: `len(object.__subclasses__())` is 495...

Comment: @chepner I only need the caller child class name, not all of them :)

Comment: Are you calling this from an instance of `Person` or `Employee`?

Comment: @iso_9001_ That only works until someone decides to subclass `Person` *twice*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with `type(self).__name__`.

`type(self)` gets the actual class of `self`, even if called in a base class.

All classes have a `__name__` attribute which gives their name as a string.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You need `__subclasses__()``` to access child classes.

Comment: @BugsBuggy: I think the most common use case for this question is to get the class of a given instance. With `__subclasses__`, there's no instance whose class to get. Maybe the OP wasn't completely explicit, but IMO, `__subclasses__` goes beyond the scope of what they're asking.

Comment: You do not really need an instance to call subclass. The question states that it needs name of `child` class from parent class.